# d3 line chart not showing data - based of tutorial

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am having issues with my line chart not showing data. I am basing my code off of [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245.). I am using WebStorm and there are no errors in my code or the developer tools in Chrome so I'm at a loss for what is going wrong.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y");

    var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.users); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("lineChart.csv", type, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.users; }));

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end");

        svg.append("path")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", line);
    });

    function type(d) {
        d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
        d.users = +d.users;
        return d;
    }

</script>
```

CSV:

```
date, users
6-Mar-15,19
11-Mar-15,12
22-Apr-15,22
29-Apr-15,32
3-May-15,1
6-May-15,9
4-Sep-15,2
8-Sep-15,13
10-Sep-15,147
21-Sep-15,4
1-Oct-15,264
4-Oct-15,114
7-Oct-15,63
12-Oct-15,79
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to be found within the header line of your CSV. You have a space character right in front of column header `users`:

```
date, users
6-Mar-15,19
```

[`d3.csv.parse()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) will turn this into an attribute `d[" users"]` containing a space character. Because there is no attribute `users` in the parsed data's objects, your accessor function `type(d)` will therefore convert `+undefined` to `NaN` and assign this value to `d["users"]`.

[image]

This is in compliance with [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) which states:

> #### 2.  Definition of the CSV Format

> 4. Within the header and each record, there may be one or more
>    fields, separated by commas.  Each line should contain the same
>    number of fields throughout the file. **Spaces are considered part
>    of a field and should not be ignored.** The last field in the
>    record must not be followed by a comma.

The solution to your problem will be as simple as removing the unwanted space character from your CSV while leaving the rest unchanged:

```
date,users
6-Mar-15,19
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine when using static data. So you should conform the data is loaded correctly inside d3.csv method and converted properly using type function.

Ensure `date` is parsed and `users` is an aggregated sum.

**EDIT:** Try loading csv data as shown below.

```
d3.csv("lineChart.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
      d.users = +d.users;
    });
    ---------------------
    ---------------------
});
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y");

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.users);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "date": "6-Mar-15",
  "users": 19
}, {
  "date": "11-Mar-15",
  "users": 12
}, {
  "date": "22-Apr-15",
  "users": 22
}, {
  "date": "29-Apr-15",
  "users": 32
}, {
  "date": "3-May-15",
  "users": 1
}, {
  "date": "6-May-15",
  "users": 9
}, {
  "date": "4-Sep-15",
  "users": 2
}, {
  "date": "8-Sep-15",
  "users": 13
}, {
  "date": "10-Sep-15",
  "users": 147
}, {
  "date": "21-Sep-15",
  "users": 4
}, {
  "date": "1-Oct-15",
  "users": 264
}, {
  "date": "4-Oct-15",
  "users": 114
}, {
  "date": "7-Oct-15",
  "users": 63
}, {
  "date": "12-Oct-15",
  "users": 79
}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
  d.users = +d.users;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(data));

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.users;
}));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How would I go about converting it? I've been trying everything and nothing seems to work

Comment: I have added an alert with the converted data. Compare your data with the same.

Comment: It's the same, but I need to be able to do it importing a csv file

Comment: yeah I understand. Check the data you get inside d3.csv function is same as the data alerted above. It should work in that case. And recheck the styles added.